# Ubuntu support on lenovo flex 14

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lenovo, touchscreen

I am just considering buying a new laptop . With all the diversity , my best solution ( considering budget ) was the lenovo flex 14 .
I am a big ubuntu fan , and I don't want to end up using the windows 8 . I was asking if a dual boot on lenovo flex 14 is possible , and if the touch screen will work just flawlessly using a Lenovo Flex 14

Comment: You might want to look at the problems somebody else had with a [Flex 15](http://askubuntu.com/questions/398568/ubuntu-13-10-touchpad-drivers-not-working-synaptics-not-loaded-lenovo-ideapad).

Comment: I already read it ! I am just checking if anyone had the flex 14 and ubuntu on it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just did the same. Bought lenovo flex 14, and installed ubuntu 13.10 alongside the preinstalled windows 8. I now have a dual boot.

I mostly followed the instructions from this thread: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). I had to make a few modifications though.

The touch screen works fine. I have not faced any trouble so far.

Answer (score 3):

The touchsreen works well, but not in the same way as in windows. Here are some tips:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch

It works well with Unity, but with Xfce it works as a simple mouse cursor.
And it is working very well in Chromium, but not so with Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

In India, you get a version of this with AMD A6 processor, 4GB RAM and 500 GB disk. I couldn't get Ubuntu 14.04.1 to work satisfactorily on this (everything was detected out of the box, but Compiz used  up 100% of CPU all the time). Switched to Mint XFCE edition and I had to do some tweaks to get Wifi to work, display drivers etc - setup documented at http://vsbabu.org/mt/archives/2014/09/16/setting_up_xubuntu_in_lenovo_flex2_14d.html

Answer (score 1):

I got the version with AMD A8 processor working with the kernel parameter acpi_osi="Linux". Now everything works, acpi, quad core cpu in virtualbox, correct power down.

Answer (score 1):

For everybody who is considering Ubuntu (15) as OS on the Lenovo flex 2: I highly recommend it. My experience was flawless. It worked out of the box, no bs with drivers as with win 7 and win 10. And I cannot imagine ever going back to Windows again. Ubuntu really is a pleasure to the eye on my HD screen. Touch however, does not work so well but the rest compensates for that enough.