# “psmouse.ko' not found” installing ALPS touchpad in a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 14

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo, ideapad, alps

I was following this instructions with Ubuntu 14.04.
https://github.com/he1per/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7 and [psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad in a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398568/psmouse-serio1-alps-unknown-alps-touchpad-in-a-lenovo-ideapad-flex-15)

And after many tries I received the following error message:

> root@alisson-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex14:/tmp/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7# ./install.sh
>   ────── Building with dkms ───────
>
> Error! DKMS tree already contains: psmouse-dkms-alpsv7-1.0
>   You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
>   Module psmouse-dkms-alpsv7/1.0 already built for kernel 3.13.0-24-generic/4
>
> ────── Installing with dkms ───────
>
> Module psmouse-dkms-alpsv7/1.0 already installed on kernel 3.13.0-24-generic/x86_64
>   ▶▶▶▶ Error: dkms install failed:\n    '/usr/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic//updates/psmouse.ko' not found.
>   root@alisson-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex14:/tmp/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7#

than, searching for "psmouse.ko":

> alisson@alisson-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex14:~$ locate psmouse.ko
>   /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko
>   /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/updates/dkms/psmouse.ko
>   /var/lib/dkms/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7/1.0/3.13.0-24-generic/x86_64/module/psmouse.ko
>   /var/lib/dkms/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7/1.0/build/src/.psmouse.ko.cmd
>   /var/lib/dkms/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7/1.0/build/src/psmouse.ko
>   alisson@alisson-Lenovo-Ideapad-Flex14:~$

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my Lenovo Ideapad Z510.
Touchpad was recognized as PS/2 Mouse. No configuration available for scrolling or disabling while typing. Scrolling did not work.

I installed Kernel 3.14.1 then everything worked fine after reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday I did a normal update asked by ubuntu and today to my surprise the two fingers option has begun to function!