# ALPS touchpad detected as PS/2, corrected with psmouse-dkms-alpsv7 but reset after reboot

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, settings, alps

Hope someone can help me a little with this problem.
I have a Lenovo Ideapad Z510, with a ALPS touchpad. And OS = Kubuntu 14.04 (Windows 8.1 alongside with it)

The touchpad is detected as an PS/2 mouse. Using this guide https://askubuntu.com/a/417518/262262, and some minor edits, managed I to get it to work, and multitouch is working as it should. But after reboot, all settings went back, as it was before the psmouse-dkms-alpsv7 modification.

Is it possible to make the changes permanent?

### Before changes:

The touchpad is detected as an PS/2 mouse:

```
    chp@chp-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510-kubuntu:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4027       id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

dmesg writes:

```
chp@chp-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510-kubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep -i alps
[    1.457466] psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=73 03 0a, EC=88 b6 06
```

### The changes:

I started to follow the guide (https://askubuntu.com/a/417518/262262), but every time I restartet the PC, the GIT folder was deleted. So I moved it to /msp instead. (chmod 777)

file = install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash  #  changed from: #!/bin/bash

#old line: MDIR="/usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)"
MDIR="/lib/modules/$(uname -r)"

#old line: NEWMDIR="$MDIR/${DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]}"
NEWMDIR="$MDIR${DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]}"
```

file = dkms.conf

```
#old line: DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates"
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION[0]="/updates/dkms"
```

and then installed it. The modifications in the above files, prevented errors under install.

### Results:

```
chp@chp-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510-kubuntu:/psm/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7$ sudo ./install.sh
[sudo] password for chp: 
────── Building with dkms ───────

Error! DKMS tree already contains: psmouse-dkms-alpsv7-1.0
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
Module psmouse-dkms-alpsv7/1.0 already built for kernel 3.13.0-32-generic/4
 ** Old module backed up as:
    '/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko.orig'


────── Installing with dkms ───────

Module psmouse-dkms-alpsv7/1.0 already installed on kernel 3.13.0-32-generic/x86_64
Install succeded:
    '/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/updates/dkms/psmouse.ko' found and copied to:
    '/lib/modules/3.13.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/input/mouse/psmouse.ko'
──→ rmmod psmouse
──→ modprobe psmouse
ok.
```

xinput:

```
chp@chp-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510-kubuntu:/psm/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7$ xinput --list                                     
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]                                   
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]                                   
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:4027       id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]                           
⎜   ↳ ALPS PS/2 Device                          id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]                                   
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]                                   
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]                                   
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]                                   
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]                                   
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]                                   
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]                                   
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]                                   
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]                                   
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]                                   
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

dmesg:

```
chp@chp-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510-kubuntu:/psm/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7$ dmesg | grep -i alps
[    1.457466] psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad: E7=73 03 0a, EC=88 b6 06
[ 2072.514926] input: ALPS PS/2 Device as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input18
[ 2072.536678] input: AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input17
```

synclient:

```
chp@chp-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z510-kubuntu:/psm/psmouse-dkms-alpsv7$ synclient -l                
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 614
    RightEdge               = 3481
    TopEdge                 = 307
    BottomEdge              = 1740
    FingerLow               = 12
    FingerHigh              = 15
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 201
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 75
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 141
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 91
    HorizScrollDelta        = 91
    VertEdgeScroll          = 1
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0436872
    TouchpadOff             = 0
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 1
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 100
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 15
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 80
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 1
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 22
    VertHysteresis          = 22
    ClickPad                = 0
```

Comment: Try this: Follow this step by step and you will get it working: [Multitouch fix for Alps touchpad](https://nwoki.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/multitouch-fix-for-alps-touchpad/) Then execute these lines in terminal: sudo update-initramfs -u

Answer (score 0):

You only need to install the DKMS package once, it will be copied to `/var/lib/dkms/`. So, `/tmp/` was fine, and you really should not create `/msp/` either as it violates the Filesystem Hierarchy guidelines.

My guess is that `psmouse` is considered a crucial module which should be available when Ubuntu boots, and therefore ends up in the initial ramdisk. As your new module replaced an existing module (`psmouse`), you can try to run the `sudo update-initramfs -u` to get your new module in the initrd. You only need to do this once as further kernel updates will trigger this automatically.