# Drivers for Lenovo Thinkpad E550 Touchpad

Tags: touchpad, scrolling

I have just received my new laptop, a:

Lenovo Notebook ThinkPad E550

And have installed Ubuntu version:

14.04.1 LTS

To my disappointment, it does not seem to be possible at all to scroll using the touchpad. Neither using the two finger gesture, nor by holding down the centre button.

A quick google search turned up

[This web page](http://support.lenovo.com/en/documents/ht062562)

Which, though it does not list this particular model, implies that it may be a driver problem. Unsurprisingly, Lenovo does not seem to supply a driver for Ubuntu, so I was wondering if anybody here had any suggestions?

---

Edit in accordance with pilot6's comment:

```
xinput; dmesg | grep pnp
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
[    0.274300] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.274738] pnp 00:02: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0103 (active)
[    0.274745] pnp 00:03: [dma 4]
[    0.274756] pnp 00:03: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0200 (active)
[    0.274770] pnp 00:04: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0800 (active)
[    0.274792] pnp 00:05: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0c04 (active)
[    0.274811] pnp 00:06: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs PNP0b00 (active)
[    0.274831] pnp 00:07: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs LEN0071 PNP0303 (active)
[    0.274852] pnp 00:08: Plug and Play ACPI device, IDs LEN200c PNP0f13 (active)
[    0.275593] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 10 devices
```

Comment: I used this solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/398568/psmouse-serio1-alps-unknown-alps-touchpad-in-a-lenovo-ideapad-flex-15?answertab=votes#tab-top, and got some improvement: the scrolling now works, but the the touchpad keys are not anymore.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput; dmesg | grep pnp` terminal command.

Comment: First upgrade kernel as described in one of the answers. `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid` and reboot. If that does not help, then we can continue.

Comment: Yep, that seems to've done it, thanks @Pilot6, I've also up-voted the answer

Comment: You can accept it too.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. I think I will :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this (I have the same laptop) on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation using a newer kernel (v3.19+ from Vivid or later). I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

did a reboot and the touchpad seems to be working now ([source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1431338/comments/3)).

Other people seem to be able to solve this problem by using a newer kernel too:
https://github.com/duncan-bayne/mint-setup/issues/41

Also, if you have VirtualBox, your computer will keep reporting or bugs, a possible workaround is to uninstall to VirtualBox and install the latest one.

Comment: Do you have exactly same laptop model? Or you just fixed "some similar problem" this way?

Comment: I do have the exact same laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add here, that I looked up the specific linux kernel for my distribution. I've had the same problem on the Thinkpad E555 with Ubuntu 16-LTS, and used

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

Which is specific for the new Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (xenial) distribution. It's working great.

Comment: Just as an Info: This did not resolve the problem on my Thinkpad E550. hwinfo delivers: `I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0000
  N: Name="PS/2 Generic Mouse"
  P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
  S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input4
  U: Uniq=
  H: Handlers=mouse0 event4 
  B: PROP=0
  B: EV=7
  B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  B: REL=3` and `uname -a`: `Linux elmo 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:00:59 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux`