# Touchpad on Thinkpad E550 is recognized as mouse. No Scrolling possible

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad, scrolling

i bought a new Thinkpad E550 and installed Ubuntu 14.10. Works fine, except the touchpad is not recognized properly. Scrolling isn't possible, working without isn't working for me ;). It seems, that that the touchpad is recognized as PS/2 Generic Mouse, as xinput -list is outputting:

```
xxx@xxx-ThinkPad-E550:~$ xinput -list
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
 ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                       id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
 ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard              id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ Power Button                             id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ Video Bus                                id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ Video Bus                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ Integrated Camera                        id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard             id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
 ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                   id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

It's seems to be, as if some driver were necessary, but I couldn't find some for my E550. In the Mouse/Touchpad secction in settings, there're just the mouse options.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used this solution [psmouse serio1: alps: Unknown ALPS touchpad in a Lenovo Ideapad Flex 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398568/psmouse-serio1-alps-unknown-alps-touchpad-in-a-lenovo-ideapad-flex-15?answertab=votes#tab-top), and got some improvement: the scrolling now works, but the the touchpad keys are not working anymore.