# after last Update Touchpad stoped working

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, touchpad, lenovo, alps

I have a lenovo z510 which has an ALPS v7 touchpad. After the new installation of xubuntu 14.04 I used [this fix](https://askubuntu.com/questions/398568/psmouse-serio1-alps-unknown-alps-touchpad-in-a-lenovo-ideapad-flex-15/417518#417518) to make it work. Now, After the latest kernel-update it doesn't get recognized anymore.

```
    xinput
 ⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
 ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4    [slave       pointer       (2)]
 ⎜   ↳ Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                       id=14   [slave       pointer  (2)]
 ⎣
```

I'm still running xubuntu 14.04, current Kernel 3.16.0-60-generic x86_64

edit: well, that look weird

```
dkms status
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-67-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-68-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-71-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-73-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.13.0-77-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-55-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-56-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-57-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.7, 3.16.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.13.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.13.0-71-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.13.0-73-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.13.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.13.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.13.0-77-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.16.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.16.0-55-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.16.0-56-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.16.0-57-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.16.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-352, 352.63, 3.16.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.13.0-67-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.13.0-68-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.13.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff      between built and installed module!)
psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.13.0-71-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.13.0-73-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff     between built and installed module!)
psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.13.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.13.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff     between built and installed module!)
psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.13.0-77-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.16.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff     between built and installed module!)
 psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.16.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
 psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.16.0-55-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
 psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.16.0-56-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
 psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.16.0-57-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.16.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
 psmouse, alps-1.3, 3.16.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
 psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.13.0-67-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
 psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.13.0-68-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
 psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.13.0-70-generic, x86_64: installed
 psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.13.0-71-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
 psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.13.0-73-generic, x86_64: installed
 psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.13.0-74-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.13.0-76-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.13.0-77-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.16.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.16.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.16.0-55-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.16.0-56-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.16.0-57-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.16.0-59-generic, x86_64: installed
psmouse-dkms-alpsv7, 1.1, 3.16.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Comment: So get it work again the same way.

Comment: I already tried that. But output says module is already installed.

Comment: But I suggest removing that package and installing new kernel. `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily`. It should work without custom fixes.

Comment: How exactly do I remove it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dkms status`.

Comment: You installed too many wrong packages.

Comment: I see. And I have no idea how I remove them. That's why I need direct help. :)

Comment: Hold on. I am writing an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest removing all custom packages and upgrading the kernel. Run:

```
sudo dkms remove psmouse/alps-1.3 --all
sudo dkms remove psmouse-dkms-alpsv7/1.1 --all
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Reboot.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing a fast and simple solution! Everything works fine now!